# How does System.Windows.Input.Cursors know what the cursors should look like?

Tags: c#, .net, xaml

The specific implementation of the code in question is as follows:

We have a split application, where the left side displays a list of search results, and the right side displays the details of the selected result.  Between the two we have a `<Gridsplitter>` object so that each side can be re-sized.  The line of code in our app is  this:

```
<GridSplitter Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="3" Panel.ZIndex="100" MouseEnter="GridSplitter_MouseEnter" MouseLeave="GridSplitter_MouseLeave" Grid.RowSpan="2"/>
```

I looked at our method for `GridSplitter_MouseEnter` and `GridSplitter_MouseLeave` and found that they called the System.Windows.Input.Cursors class, one to change the cursor to the sideways arrows and one to return the cursor to the standard clicker arrow.  Both methods are here:

```
private void GridSplitter_MouseEnter(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    Mouse.OverrideCursor = System.Windows.Input.Cursors.SizeWE;
}

private void GridSplitter_MouseLeave(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    Mouse.OverrideCursor = System.Windows.Input.Cursors.Arrow;
}
```

I then looked at the System.Windows.Input.Cursors class to see the definitions of these little clip-art bastards, but I can't figure it out.  Below is the code from the SizeWE method.

```
//
// Summary:
//     Gets a two-headed west/east sizing System.Windows.Input.Cursor.
//
// Returns:
//     A two-headed west/east sizing cursor.
public static Cursor SizeWE { get; }
```

I tried opening C:\Program Files\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework.NETFramework\v4.0\PresentationCore.dll with VS2012 to no avail.  I realize it's something I should just overlook and accept as 'the way it works' but that's just not how my mind works.

Like I said, I know it's probably either stupidly simple or as basic as asking someone how to breathe, but where does the method actually get the little <-> image of the cursor?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are almost there. The Cursor class calls a native method, which loads cursors using user32.dll. I would assume that the standard cursor icons are resources embedded in that DLL.

Comment: +1: [LoadCursor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms648391(v=vs.85).aspx) function have list of resources.